# Salt Lake Temple: window bordering

Tags: building, design, window

I'm trying to replicate the stonework above the arched windows on the main side of the Salt lake temple.

[image: closeup of windws]

my current approach is to use a combination of
1x2 SNOT brick to face outward
1x2 jumper plate to center
cheese slope to represent the small knob at the center top of the window

[image]

I'd like to solicit suggestions on my current setup as well as suggestions about how to add the horizontal stone edging above the windows.  I'm considering some combination of [double slopes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=79756&C=86#T=C&C=86) but they seem just a bit too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a combination of [1x2 plate with door rail](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32028) plus [4 x 2½ x 1⅔ mudguard with arch](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50745).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe part number [30586](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30586&ccName=4222019)? "Plate, Modified 2 x 8 with Door Rail"

Comment: yea, I considered those, but they have kind of an 'industrial' look - like it looks like something in a factory or steel mill.